# Создать процесс, общий обработчик для всех сайтов

Tags: php

Ubuntu 16.04. Имеется php-скрипт: самописный сборщик статистики посещения моего сайта. Суть его работы в следующем: на каждый запрос к моему сайту формируется строка в БД, в которой фиксируются параметры запроса. Для каждого сайта свой сборщик статистики.

Так как сайтов на сервере много и посещений каждого сайта не мало, появляется необходимость как-то оптимизировать работу сборщиков статистики.

Идея такая: в памяти висит какой-то процесс (желательно на php). Все мои сборщики статистики (со всех сайтов) отправляют ему данные. Каждые 30 секунд или когда накопиться, например, 1000 записей, процесс записывает их в базу данных.
Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1):

> Все мои сборщики статистики (со всех сайтов) отправляют ему данные. Каждые 30 секунд или когда накопиться, например, 1000 записей, процесс записывает их в базу данных. Как это можно сделать?

Через crontab запускать процесс записи с нужной периодичностью.   Руководство: `man crontab`

Да - и не нужно, чтоб процесс какой висел - просто Ваши сборщики пусть записывают в файл, построчно, например, а отттуда брать массивом и раскладывать для записи в базу - и просто запускать cronom скрипт, который будет делать это.
Нисчего не висит, все красиво, оптимально и элегантно.

Comment: Полностью согласен с автором, чтобы висел лишний процесс, который еще и в себе будет скапливать данные а потом массово их вставлять в БД - "бомбическое решение" :), Записывать данные во временные файлы, тем самым создавать "имитацию" кэша, и потом через cron запускать php скрипт каждые 30 секунд, который будет брать данные из файла и вставлять в бд, затем очищать его.

Answer (score 1):

В целом, всё довольно просто:

1. Пишем скрипт, который умеет ждать коннекта на порт и парсить то что ему приходит
2. Приходящие данные скрипт должен уметь кешировать, при необходимости - усреднять и так далее
3. Пишется [systemd service unit](https://habr.com/ru/company/southbridge/blog/255845/), который будет демонизировать скрипт

Дьявол, как всегда, в мелочах. Во первых, если надо оптимизировать, то это явно не php. Нужен, хотя бы golang или python. Во вторых, нужно понять где бутылочное горлышко, действительно ли это именно БД? В третьих, если это реляционная БД, то переход на nosql может существенно ускорить работу с данными.

Ну а вообще, предлагаю использовать стек [prometheus](https://prometheus.io/)("бд") + [grafana](https://grafana.com/)(dashboards, "графики") + [node_exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter)/[telegraf](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf) (сборщики метрик) (про установку можно почитать, например, [тут](https://eax.me/prometheus-and-grafana/)). Этот стек позволит не только не задумываться о том, как хранить данные, но и позволяет гибко настраивать графики. А сборщики метрик не только имеют "из коробки" довольно большое количество вариантов собираемых метрик, но и позволяют легко себя расширять.